# Ubuntu vm shared folder file copy uses cached version

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, filemanager

I have setup a shared folder where I have put images, however Ubuntu uses somehow the cached/old version when I try to copy the newest one.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64bit virtual machine with Virtualbox.

How can I fix this?

(this only happends through the file explorer the `$ cp /x /y` command works.)